# How to change html Ajax content when clicking on the back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a search page with filter.
When the user change the filter values, I add parameters to the URL to prevent the values if the user refreshed the page

```js
q       = $('#form input[name=q]').val(),
srchtype= $('#filter input[name=srchtype]:checked').val(),
sortBy  = $('#filter select#sortBy').val(),
parameters = "q="+qVal+"&srchType="+srchType+"&sortBy="+sortBy;
history.pushState(null, null, '?'+parameters);
```

then I get the data using Ajax

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: parameters+"&_token="+_token
}).done(data => {
    // Javascript Code
});
```

The problem is that when the user click on the browser's back button, the URL will change to the previous one, but the data on the page will not change.

Comment: Make sure you always read parameters from the URL first

Comment: So when the user click on the "back" button, I should read the parameters and load the previous data again using Ajax?

Comment: It's hard to tell, you're skimping on the code you're showing us. I'm saying you should parse the parameter from the URL first, and if they're not there, then you use the default values. It seems that your $.ajax call is hardcoded to read the initial values

Comment: Thank you @JuanMendes, I posted an answer with the solution I tried, it works fine.
Could you check and tell me is it the best way?

Comment: Sorry, it's still hard to tell but I can't see code that is reading the parameters from the URL, only setting it. Glad you figured it out but you should work on your question asking skills to get more meaningful answer. Your question is missing lots of important pieces and is not self contained.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and it works :D

```js
history.replaceState($('body').html(), null) // store the first body html

q       = $('#form input[name=q]').val(),
srchtype= $('#filter input[name=srchtype]:checked').val(),
sortBy  = $('#filter select#sortBy').val(),
parameters = "q="+qVal+"&srchType="+srchType+"&sortBy="+sortBy;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: parameters
}).done(data => {
    // Javascript Code

    history.pushState($('body').html(), null, '?'+parameters); // store the next body html and url
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).